# Converting JSON urls to regular urls from an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax

I'm currently retrieving data for my Rails app and one attribute in particular that I wish to use is an instance's `url`. I noticed that doing something like this would yield the json url:

```
data.url // http://localhost:3000/games/1.json
```

I'd like to get the url without the `.json` appended to the url. I figured this could be done using `replace()` but felt it was a bit too *hard-coded*:

```
data.url.replace(".json", ""));
```

I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this either through pre-formatting my json returns in my Rails controller or through Javascript itself?

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON("/games.json", function(data) {
    data.map(function(data, index) {
      return data.url.replace(".json", ""));
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You can make use of `substring` & `lastIndexOf` as mentioned in the answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to lock down yourself with `.json` hard-coded extension, you can get the `lastIndexOf` of `.` & get the `substring` from 0.

I guess this will do the trick!

```
var url = data.url;
console.log(url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('.')));
```

Hope it helps!